# Remove all <div>....</div> tags and everything inside them from a string

Tags: python

I have the following lines in a string:

```
<div style=""width:20px;float:left;""><img alt="""" src=""../../images/btnpdf.gif""></div>
<div style=""float:left; padding-top:2px;""><a target=""_blank"" style="""" href=""888"">Text</a></div>
<div style=""clear:left;""></div>
<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" DE</a>
<div style=""height:0px;clear:left""></div>
<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" FR</a>
<div style=""height:0px;clear:left""></div>
<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" IT</a>
<div style=""height:0px;clear:left""></div>
```

and I want to remove everything listed above from the string.

Comment: Have you considered using a [parser](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, in addition to given example, handles also typical case when xml element is split over few lines:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'<div.*?<\/div>\s*','',text, flags=re.DOTALL))

<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" DE</a>                                                                                                              
<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" FR</a>                                                                                                              
<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" IT</a>
```

Explanation:

- `re.DOTALL` - makes `.` match any character, including newline
- `.*?` - non-greedy version of `.*`, which means that it will stop when the first occurrence of `</div>` is found

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

print([x for x in re.sub(r'<div(.*)<\/div>','',text).splitlines() if x != ''])

['<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" DE</a>',
 '<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" FR</a>',
 '<a class=""btnMore"" target=""_blank"" href=""******/"">Text"" IT</a>']
```

For something more complex, you should use a parser like beautifulsoup4